# How to monitor the usage of the ADX dashboard?

Tags: dashboard, azure-data-explorer, adx

I created an Azure Data Explorer dashboard.
How can I monitor its usage?
Who is using it and when?

Answer (score 2):

client activity ID for queries has the following structure:

```
RTD;<dashbaord>;<executionId>
```

you can get the dashboard id from the dashboard URL

```
.show queries  
| where ClientActivityId startswith "RTD;"
| parse ClientActivityId with "RTD;" DashboardId ";" ExecutionId
| project DashboardId, ExecutionId
```